# AngularJS - Dynamically created <textarea> using ngSanitize doesn't show (other elements do)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngsanitize

I'm a `AngularJS` newbie and trying to dynamically create a `textarea` upon a `button` click. I'm using the `ngSanitize` addon, the code works, I'm able to insert plain `div`s with some text, but when the matter comes to create a `textarea` it just won't work. The element doesn't even show.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn bg-info" ng-click="insertReplyBox()">Reply</button>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2" id="replyBox">
    <div ng-bind-html="replyBoxHTML"></div>
    <div ng-bind-html="replyBoxHTML1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS (angular controller)

```
app.controller('messagesReadController', function($scope) {
  $scope.insertReplyBox = function() {
    console.log("reply clicked");

    $scope.replyBoxHTML = '<div>This works!!</div>';
    $scope.replyBoxHTML1 = '<textarea col="4" row="20" placeholder="placeholder"></textarea>'; //this doesn't work
  }
});
```

(I have added the `ngSanitize` dependency in another file, so it doesn't show here.)

Comment: can you create sample plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it the wrong way, with angularJS you should avoid a maximum to play with DOM like that (except for directives)

What about this ?

```
<button class="btn bg-info" ng-click="textareashow = !textareashow">Reply</button>
 <br>
 <div class="row" ng-show="textareashow">
   <div class="col-lg-2" id="replyBox">
     <textarea col="4" row="20" placeholder="placeholder"></textarea>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This achieves my goal and quite easy to implement\understand. Could you explain why isn't it recommended do play with DOM elements?

Comment: angularjs provide a new thinking of front-end development, there is almost always a way to do what you want without injecting code, your controller should never have html inside.

Comment: I'm not clear, it's difficult to explain but you will get it soon i think

Answer (score 3):

use unsafe

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('messagesReadController', function($scope) {
  $scope.insertReplyBox = function() {
    console.log("reply clicked");

    $scope.replyBoxHTML = '<div>This works!!</div>';
    $scope.replyBoxHTML1 = '<textarea col="4" row="20" placeholder="placeholder"></textarea>'; //this doesn't work
  }
});

 app.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="messagesReadController">

<button class="btn bg-info" ng-click="insertReplyBox()">Reply</button>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2" id="replyBox">
    <div ng-bind-html="replyBoxHTML"></div>
    <div ng-bind-html="replyBoxHTML1| unsafe"   ></div>
  </div>
</div>

 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what does `unsafe` mean using this method?